# Not able to run the examples of HBase-The definitive guide

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to run examples from HBase-The definitve guide and i've been encountering with this error and i'm not able to get past it. I'm running in Stand alone mode if that helps.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: �
17136@ubuntulocalhost,32992,1373877731444
at    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:615)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)  
at util.HBaseHelper.<init>(HBaseHelper.java:29)  
at util.HBaseHelper.getHelper(HBaseHelper.java:33)  
at client.PutExample.main(PutExample.java:22)
```

But my HMaster process is running:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/hbase-book/ch03$ jps
17602 Jps
8709 NameNode
8929 DataNode
9472 TaskTracker
9252 JobTracker
9172 SecondaryNameNode
17136 HMaster
```

This is my hbase-site.xml file:

```
<configuration>  
<property>  
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>  
<value>file:///usr/local/hbase/hbase-data/</value>  
</property>  
<property>  
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>  
<value>/usr/local/hbase/zookeeper-data/</value>
```

This is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
127.0.0.1       ubuntu.ubuntu-domain ubuntu
```

Specifically, i'm trying to run the 3rd chapter examples and i'm just not understanding why my setup is not running..

Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Edit: Here are the logs:

```
2013-07-15 03:56:32,663 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:60119
2013-07-15 03:56:32,672 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Connection request from old client /127.0.0.1:60119; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2013-07-15 03:56:32,672 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:60119
2013-07-15 03:56:32,674 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x13fe17e7f1d0006 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:60119
2013-07-15 03:57:11,653 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=1.17 MB, free=247.24 MB, max=248.41 MB, blocks=2, accesses=68, hits=55, hitRatio=80.88%, , cachingAccesses=61, cachingHits=53, cachingHitsRatio=86.88%, , evictions=0, evicted=6, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2013-07-15 03:57:14,333 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13fe17e7f1d0006, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-07-15 03:57:14,334 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:60119 which had sessionid 0x13fe17e7f1d0006
2013-07-15 03:57:24,551 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Skipping load balancing because balanced cluster; servers=1 regions=1 average=1.0 mostloaded=1 leastloaded=1
2013-07-15 03:57:24,568 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner: Scanning .META. starting at row= for max=2147483647 rows using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@189ddf
2013-07-15 03:57:24,578 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor: Scanned 1 catalog row(s) and gc'd 0 unreferenced parent region(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with standalone or distributed mode. Make sure your setup is working fine. I can see that RegionServer and Zookeeper are not running. Comment out the line **127.0.1.1       ubuntu** in your **/etc/hosts** file and restart HBase. You might have to kill it.

P.S : Since you already have Hadoop configured and it is running fine, you can run HBase in pseudo-distributed setup.

Comment: Here are the logs:
2013-07-15 20:29:15,365 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13fe585610d0003, likely client has closed socket at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220) at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-07-15 20:29:15,372 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:55200 which had sessionid 0x13e